# Area function of a curve

Tags: calculus

I used to understand there exist a area function A(x) that give the area under function f(x) from 0 to x. That is say f(x) = $3x^2$ then the area function A(x) of f(x)=$3x^2$ will be $x^3$.

$\int 3x^2 dx = x^3 + c $

Here the curve is f(x)=$3x^2$ and its area function A(x) =$x^3$.

It works for positive x values but gives negative value for x=-2, it gives area as -8. Why?

Please correct my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: There are issues with thinking that your integrals immediately translate to what we commonly understand as areas (which are unsigned). But even retaining your mode of thinking, have you tried thinking in terms of "increasing $x$ direction"? Since $0 > -2$, try reversing the bounds.

Comment: Integrals are not areas, they're signed areas. You'll need to integrate over the negative and positive sections separately then ensure the areas are positive, then add them together. Note that if you integrate between $-1$ and $1$ that it's zero, but the area is not zero which shows the importance of keeping track of the sign.

Comment: You say "the area under function $f(x)$" but *under* makes less sense when $f(x)<0$ so you need a reasonable reinterpretation

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $A(x)$ is the antiderivative, not the area function per se. When calculating area from a to b, you do the following:
$\int_a^b3x^2dx = A(b)-A(a)$. So the area between -2 and 0 is $A(0) - A(-2) = 8$. What you're doing is essentially calculating the area 'backwards', you're calculating the integral $\int_0^{-2}3x^2dx$, which is equal to $-\int^0_{-2}3x^2dx$

Comment: The region of integration must have the same sign to ensure that it represents an area. For example if you choose $a=-1$ and $b=1$ then the integral will be $0$, which is not the area under the curve on that region.

Comment: @CyclotomicField $A(1) - A(-1) = 1 +1 = 2$

Comment: I was integrating $x^3$ instead of $3x^2$. In general any function which isn't strictly positive will require you to divide the region of integration or integrate $\vert f(x) \vert$ instead.